# Transferring databases between SQL Server instances

Tags: sql-server

I have mdf & ldf files from another machine and want to add these databases to my machine, how can I do that?......Thanks

When I try to attach the database I get the following error:

> Error 602: could not find row in
>   sysindexes for database id 7 object id
>   1. Run DBCC CHECKTABLE

Comment: Please edit this and make two entries - one for each question.  Please make the title more descriptive as well - in the form of a question.  Then you may get some assistance.

Comment: Two poorly formatted questions...

Comment: The first part appears to be an error generated when trying to do the the second part.  I have re-written the question to make it more like a single question.

Comment: Thanks for your response guys and sorry for this will provide a clean and more clear question from now on.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to attach files created by a newer version of SQL Server, that may be your problem

Answer (score 1):

Second question - use [`sp_attach_db`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259611(SQL.80).aspx).